# loopj android-async-http error

Tags: android-studio, loopj

I downloaded the android-async-http-1.4.8.jar and put it under the app->libs folder.  Then add the following code in the MainActivity.

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // called before request is started
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
            textViewDailyTip.setText(response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
        }

        @Override
        public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
            // called when request is retried
        }
    });
```

but I got the error.

```
Error:(50, 9) error: cannot access AsyncHttpClient
bad class file: /Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/yan.com/Yin/app/libs/android-async-http-1.4.8.jar(com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.class)
unable to access file: null
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Answer (score 2):

Add dependency in the build.gradle file under app:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

taken from: [Installation & Basic Usage](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

If it didn't work, try executing the following command:

```
    gradlew installarchives
```

- It should also work without downloading the jar file.
- Another note is that I am using version 1.4.5.

Good luck!